# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, invariant-subspace

**(1) A = {  (a,b,2a-3b) |  a,b $\in $ R  }**

$ \quad$ $A = span\{ (1,0,2) , (0,1,-3) \}\ {\rm is\ a\ subspace\ of}\ \mathbb{R}^3$

**(2) $B = \{ (u,v,w) |  vw  = 0 $  }**

**$ \quad$ $ Let B = span(T).\ (1,1,0) , (1,0,1) \in B.\ (1,1,0) + (1,0,1) = (2, 1, 1) \in span(T)$,

${\rm but\ this\ is\ impossible\ as\ (2,1,1) \not \in B\ since\  vw \ne  0.\  B\ is\ not\ a\ subspace.} $**

**(3) C  = { ($d^2,e^2, f^2)$ |  d,e, f $\in $ R  }**

$ \quad$ $ Let \ d, e, f = 1, and\ C = span(T).\ (1,1,1) \in span(T) , then\ -1(1,1,1) = (-1,-1,-1) \in span(T),\ but\ this\ is\ impossible\ as\ -1 \ne d^2, e^2, f^2 since\ for\ any\ d, e, f, \in R , d^2, e^2, f^2 \ge 0\
but\ -1 < 0.\ \therefore C\ is\ not\ a\ subspace.\ $

**(4) D = { (p,q,r) |  $ \begin{pmatrix} p & q  & r \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ is singular  }**

$ \quad$ $ \begin{vmatrix} p & q & r \\ 1 & 2 & 0. \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \end{vmatrix} $ =  $ 4p - 2q + r = 0.$ $ \quad (p, q ,r) =  (s-t, 2s, 4t) =  s(1,2,0) + t(-1,0,4)\  where\ s,t \in \ R. $  $  \quad D = span\{ (1,2,0) , (-1,0,4) \} is\ a\ subspace\ of R^3 $

**(5) E  = { (x,y,z) | $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2  & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$   $ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} $  =  $ \begin{pmatrix}  2x \\ 2y \\ 2z \end{pmatrix} $  }**

$ \quad$ $ x+2y+3z = 2x, 4x+5y+6z = 2y, 7x+8y + 9z = 2z. Gauss\ Jordan\ Elimination\ gives\   $

$ \quad unique\ soln : (x,y,z) = (0,0,0).\ \therefore \ E = span\{ (0,0,0) \} is\ a\ subspace\ of R^3 $

---

I am not sure about my reasons for **(4) and (5),** please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: For (3), consider the negative real numbers. For (4), the determinant is $4p-2q+r$, but the logic is fine. For (5), I don't see the connection between the product and your equations.

Comment: I think you'll find that the answer to (5) is meant to be different for different values of $p,q,r$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, I have changed the matrix in the question for part (5), would my answer for (5) correct then?

Comment: @player3236 Right, would the counter example for (3) would be (-1,-1,-1) is a linear combination but not in C since -1 < zero ? I've corrected my answer for (3) in the qn. For (5), the matrix I wrote was wrong, I have edited it, wld the logic be fine for (5)?

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

For $4)$ you have the plane $4p-2q+r=0$ through the origin.  That's a subspace.

For $5$,  we have the kernel of $A-2I$, so it's a subspace.